# Grails executeQuery giving me "no such property" exception

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a domain class called Event:

```
class Event{
    String eventID // an ID for the event, (there are multiple events with same eventID)
    .....
}
```

In my eventService class I want to get all events with distinct eventIDs, so I have the following query:

```
Event.executeQuery("select distinct e.eventID from Event e", [max: max, offset: offset])
```

According to [the grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) it should work. However, I'm getting this error:

```
| Error 2012-05-10 18:14:09,643 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /events/event/list - 
No such property: id for class: java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: id for class: java.lang.String

Line | Method
->>   35 | run                 in C__src_Event_events_grails_app_views_event__List_gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     18 | render . . . . . .  in org.events.EventController
|     67 | list . . . . . . .  in     ''
|   1110 | runWorker           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                 in java.lang.Thread
```

I am fairly new to grails and any help would be greatly appreciated. Btw I'm using Grails 2.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by including the paging parameters, (max and offset), you are triggering the framework to attempt to create a PagedResultList.

The PagedResultList expects to hold domain objects, with ids.

However, your select statement return strings. Therefore, the message that the String class does not have an id attribute.

If you remove the paging parameters, it should work, and you should just get your list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer GreyBeardGeek. But according to the grails docs [link](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) (the third one from the top) , this should work rite?

Comment: Your query doesn't have any positionalParameters. The query that you are pointed out on that page has positional parameters.

Comment: try Event.executeQuery("select distinct e.eventID from Event e", null, [max: max, offset: offset])

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and there are two ways of doing this. GreyBeardedGeek's response was partially correct.

**First Method**

```
def eveIdList = Event.executeQuery("select distinct e.eventID from Event e", [max: max, offset: offset])
```

**Second Method**
Get the list of eventIDs:

```
def eveIdList = Event.createCriteria().list{
    projections{
        distinct("eventID")
    }
    firstResult(offset?:0)
    maxResults(max?:10)
}
```

I got a list of strings WITH length = max and offset. I was getting the error because I was trying to do String.id for each of the eventID strings. In order to get the domain objects with the corresponding eventID, I'm doing this:

```
def eveList = []
eveIdList.each{
    eveList << Event.findByEventID(it as String)
}
```

**Questions I have**

- Are they efficient?
- Is one way more efficient than the other?
- Is there a better way of solving this problem?